# Using OpenMP (libgomp) in an already multithreaded application

Tags: multithreading, qt, openmp

We are using OpenMP (libgomp) in order to speed up some calculations in a multithreaded Qt application. The parallel OpenMP sections are located within two different threads, though in fact they never execute in parallel. What we observe in this case is that 2N (where `N = OMP_THREAD_LIMIT`) omp threads are launched, apparently interfering each with the other. The calculation time is very high, while the processor load is low. Setting `OMP_WAIT_POLICY` hardly has any effect.

We also tried moving all the omp sections to a single thread (this is not a good solution for us, though, from an architectural point of view). In this case, the overall calculation time does drop and the processor is fully loaded, but only if `OMP_WAIT_POLICY` is set to `ACTIVE`. When `OMP_WAIT_POLICY == PASSIVE`, the calculation time remains low and the processor is idle 50% of time.

Odd enough, when we use omp within a single thread, the first loop parallelized using omp (in a series of omp calulations) executes 10 times slower compared to the multithread case.

**Upd:** Our questions are:

a) is there any way to reuse the openmp threads when using omp in the context of different threads.

b) Why executing with `OMP_WAIT_POLICY == PASSIVE` slows everything. Does it take so long to wake the threads?

c) Is there any logical explanation for the phenomenon of the first parallel block being so slow (even when waiting in active mode)

**Upd2:** Please mind that the issue is probably related to GNU OMP implementation. icc doesn't have it.

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question

Comment: +1. I recently considered using OpenMP in a library used by a Qt app. @Sergey: Which platform are you on?

Comment: @larsmans: We run on Linux and Windows. This phenomenon, however, has been studied only on Linux so long.

Comment: The question is vague to answer it. What your OpenMP threads are doing? Are there any data sharing? Any locks? Could you briefly write a simple code? I don't think oversubscription (running 2N) would be a big problem, though.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. As it looks now, after some research, it doesn't actually matter whatever the threads do. At the same time, oversubscription does seem to be the big problem, as setting OMP threads number even to N+1 affects the performance drastically. The threads don't even need to be doing anything. I guess it might be due to some housekeeping jobs that libgomp performs.

Comment: @Sergey Levi, can you post a small example code which can illustrate the problem and add an instructions of compiling/starting it?

Answer (score 1):

Try to start/stop openmp threads in runtime using `omp_set_num_threads(1)` and `omp_set_num_threads(cpucount)`

This call with `(1)` should stop all openmp worker threads, and call with (cpu_num) will restart them again.

So, at start of programm, run `omp_set_num_threads(1)`. 
Before omp-parallelized region, you can start omp threads even with `WAIT_POLICY=active`, and they will not consume cpu before this point.

After omp parallel region you can stop threads again.

The `omp_set_num_threads(cpucount)` call is very slow, slower than waking threads with wait_policy=passive. This can be the reason for (c) - if your libgomp starts threads only at first parallel region.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Please look at my comment above. omp_set_num_threads doesn't seem to have any affect in regard of this issue

Comment: Ooops... I've sent the previous one by mistake. Sorry for the late reply. Please look at my comment above. omp_set_num_threads doesn't seem to have any effect in regard of this issue. It looks as if an OMP worker thread has ever been created, it affects the performance, no matter whether it sleeps forever or does some work. My guess is that GOMP performs some housekeeping, waking all the threads quite often.

Comment: @Sergey Levi, waiting threads must be "docked": `gomp_barrier_wait (&pool->threads_dock);` in `libgomp/team.c`. It must sleep on futex.  Also, you are right that set_num_threads don't affect the current team thread pool.